# Output the json array of paths from bash command in github actions

Tags: linux, bash, github-actions, jq

I'm trying to create a github job that transforms a list of changed files to list of their directories in json format, but completely stuck with the
[error shown on screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN0Ie.png) (line 8: Packages/test: Is a directory). Echo command at the end shows empty string.
Action step code here:

```
- name: Get folders
    id: get-folders
    run: |
      echo "Changed packages: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.changed_files }}" 
      folders=()
      for package in ${{ steps.filter.outputs.changed_files }};
      do
        folder="$(dirname ${package})"
        folders+=("${folder}")
      done
      result=$("${folders[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -s)
      #result=$(jq --compact-output --null-input '$ARGS.positional' --args -- "${folders[@]}")
      echo '::set-output name=FOLDERS::${result}'
- run: echo "${{ steps.get-folders.outputs.FOLDERS }}"
```

Comment: `"${folders[@]}" | jq -R .` breaks because Bash tries to evaluate (run) the contents of the array, which are directory paths (produced by `dirname`), hence the error `Is a directory`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! But how to get array items as strings instead of running them as paths?

Comment: What exactly should the `result` variable contain after this line? Please make an example with concrete inputs and outputs. (Btw, the following commented-out line already shows one of many possible ways to read in the Bash array's items as a JSON array of strings. If it is commented out because it doesn't produce what you want, then please elaborate on what you wanted to get instead from that line.)

Comment: I mentioned result variable to contain list of file paths. E.g. :
`Input: Packages/pkg1/package.json, Packages/pkg2/package.json` 
`Output (result):  ["Packages/pkg1", "Packages/pkg2"]`

Commented line shows an error: "line 9: []: command not found", so I`ve tried another way to create json.

Comment: The commented-out line should do exactly what you described (for safety, you may want to wrap the Command Substitution with quotes, i.e `result="$(jq ...)"` ). Or try out this alternative using `printf` which is closer to your current attempt: `result="$(printf '%s\0' "${folders[@]}" | jq -Rcs './"\u0000"')"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ive tried that command variant with `printf` and there is no code error now. But `echo "${{ steps.get-folders.outputs.FOLDERS }}"` still returns empty string. Do you have any idea why json string could be empty? (input remains the same)

Comment: Try testing your code with real but fixed, hard-coded values, e.g. just use `echo '::set-output name=FOLDERS::["Packages/pkg1", "Packages/pkg2"]'` directly, and see what happens. I assume it would still not work as expected, yet indicate that there might be issues apart from your jq call. (Unfortunately I can't help you with the parts related to github job syntax.)

Comment: Yep, that s another error, but on git actions code side - I ll try to solve it with google. Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

```bash
YOUR_BASH_ARRAY=( a b c );
jsonString="$(jq --compact-output --null-input '$ARGS.positional' --args -- "${YOUR_BASH_ARRAY[@]}")"
```

Result: jsonString==["a","b","c"]

Credit to [pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73134494/output-the-json-array-of-paths-from-bash-command-in-github-actions#comment129169251_73134494) for calling out the answer provided by the ops' question.